# Meteor 0.9.3 meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com not deploying

Tags: meteor

I have upgraded 2 meteor apps to 0.9.3. Now, when attempting to deploy the apps to meteor.com the app is appearing to not deploy and hang. For example, here is what is displayed:

```
$ meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
$ [blinking cursor here]
```

Note that the myapp is substituted with my actual app name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I found:

1. Downgrade to 0.9.1
2. Deploy
3. Login with your developer account when it asks
4. Upgrade again to 0.9.3
5. Deploy

I think Meteor was failing to show the login prompt for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the issue.

1. Deleted the local directories with the meteor apps.
2. Pulled fresh copies of the apps from my github repos.
3. Opened the apps via the terminal and was able to publish.

I am sure that there was something deeper that was the issue, but this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was solved when i loged into my meteor account using $ meteor login